# OpenDolphin Maven on Netbeans basic config

Tags: maven, javafx, opendolphin

I'm trying to get started with JavaFX / OpenDolphin and have downloaded the jumpstart zip. When I import the Maven zip into Netbeans, I get the expected project tree. Then I try to run jumpstart_0 and get the following error:

Could not find artifact MyFirstDolphin:server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

As Maven is also new to me, I am puzzled as to where to begin solving this problem.

Two suggestions by HelpWiki are:

1. The POM misses the declaration of the repository which hosts the artifact.
2. The repository you have configured requires authentication and Maven failed to provide the correct credentials to the server. In this case, make sure your ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml contains a  declaration whose  matches the  of the remote repository to use.

Here is the current pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>MyFirstDolphin</artifactId>
    <groupId>MyFirstDolphin</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>shared</artifactId>

</project>
```

There is obviously some basic knowledge I'm lacking and it would be great if someone could shed some light on this. DolphinJumpStart doesn't work 'out of the box' in Netbeans 8 on Windows 7, so there must be others with the same problem?

Comment: Finally have a clue: there seems to be no reference to jfxrt.jar. At this point I don't know what that is (Java FX RunTime??) or where it is supposed to live, so the search goes on...

Comment: What JDK version are you using?